# Hover effect does not display hidden content

Tags: html, css

[Html Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuj93.png)

[output- hover on name and the value displays beneath, atm its visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA0Qp.png) 
.top
{
font-family: 'Brush Script MT', cursive;
font-size:50px;
}

```
  .hid{
    align-content: center;
    padding:auto 0;
    margin:0;
    display:none;
  } 

.top:hover .hid
{
  color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

I checked other similar topics, tried the combinators like + and ~, still won't work.

please help. tia

Comment: Please share the html code also

Comment: You need to set both p and hid: .top:hover .hid, .top:hover .hid p

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please click on the text above, those added description to the image content.

Comment: @Pauline, your code looked promising after so many other tries, unfortunately still does not want to display the hidden content, changes color while hovering. Anything after .top:hove, even the colors dont change, only putting a comma and adding something changes the color but does not display.

Comment: aplologies, I added different images by mistake, corrected now

Answer (score 0):

- remove `+p` cause you're hiding the entire `.hid`
- and remove the `+` in `.top:hover + .hid`

```css
  .top
  {
   font-family: 'Brush Script MT', cursive;
   font-size:50px;
  }
   
  .hid{
    display: float;
    align-content: center;
    padding:auto 0;
    margin:0;
    display:none;
  } 

.top:hover  .hid
{
  color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

you can check this https://jsfiddle.net/a178x59n/

Comment: Sorry for posting a random shot for hover effect, This was the first choice for me, I've tried different combinations around these.. Anything after top.hover, this code doest not work.

Comment: if this answer you question , please mark it as answered.

Comment: and you can check  https://jsfiddle.net/a178x59n/

Comment: its still not working, that was the first thing I tried the one you mentioned.

Comment: please provide some of your code to solve your problem

Comment: The top of the post has links to html and output shot and I have re-edited the CSS code of my post.